# Stack Exchange league reputation is wrong

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

I was looking at [league reputation](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2017-01-01/6592263#6592263) for 1 year, but it is showing more reputation than my current reputation.

How is it possible that my year reputation is greater than my total reputation?

[image: Reputation]

Comment: Caching...it's always caching!

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry but didn't understood. I was not DV recently and this (3,043) is my current reputation, so how can cache value greater than that?

Comment: @Paulie_D [maybe, maybe not](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: @JigarShah Some reputation losses (answers you earned rep on, but where the question got deleted) might not be calculated yet. Or it might be a cached value from the future, where the cache defies the linear concept of time. Who knows.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, yes it happens when question get deleted but I'm 99.99% sure that reputation did not crossed 3,050. I have checked reputation again and its same as I know how it reached to 3,043 with recent score.